# Exchange event of onclick and ondblclick event

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to exchange the event of `onclick` and `ondblclick` event in Javascript. This is my HTML page:

```
<div id="displayStatus"class="display"></div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="clickFunction()" ondblclick="doubleClick()">
<input type="button" value="Switch Event" onclick="switchEvent()">
```

I want a script for `switchEvent()` function which exchange the `onclick` and `ondblclick` events. It means after clicking "switch Event" button `onclick` should work as `ondblclick` and vice versa.

I did it like this:

```
var booleanFlag = true;

    function clickFunction(){
        if(booleanFlag)
            document.getElementById("displayStatus").innerHTML="Single Click";
        else 
            document.getElementById("displayStatus").innerHTML="Double Click";
    }
    function doubleClick(){
        if(booleanFlag)
            document.getElementById("displayStatus").innerHTML="Double Click";
        else
            document.getElementById("displayStatus").innerHTML="Single Click";
    }
            
    function switchEvent(){
        if (booleanFlag) {
            booleanFlag=false;
        }
    }
```

but this causes code repetition. Please share any better options for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No code repetition option:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="displayStatus" class="display"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="handler(false)" ondblclick="handler(true)">
    <input type="button" value="Switch Event" onclick="switchEvent()">

    <script>
        var isSwitched = false;
        var display = document.getElementById("displayStatus");

        function handler(isDoubleClick) {
            isDoubleClick = (!isSwitched && isDoubleClick) || (isSwitched && !isDoubleClick);
            display.innerHTML = isDoubleClick ? "Double Click" : "Single Click";
        }

        function switchEvent(){
            isSwitched = !isSwitched;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark as answer since it's worked for you. Thank you.

Comment: @Indrajeet4192 This solution doesn't work... it only changes the text which is being displayed. It doesn't change the button attributes. The `onclick` function and `ondblclick` functions are always the same...

Comment: @Kinduser Logic is important you can assign a function instead of printing text  `"Double Click" : "Single Click" ` .

Answer (score 0):

One function is enough. Just get the button with `document.getElementById` and change it's `onclick` attribute depending on the `booleanFlag` state.

With every click on `switchEvent` you will see in the console that the `onclick` attribute of the button changes from `clickFunction()` to `doubleClick()` and `ondblclick` changes from `doubleClick()` to `clickFunction()` and so on.

```js
var booleanFlag = true;
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

function switchEvent() {
  if (booleanFlag) {
    btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'doubleClick()');
    btn.setAttribute('ondblclick', 'clickFunction()');
    booleanFlag = false;
  }
  else {
    btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'clickFunction()');
    btn.setAttribute('ondblclick', 'doubleClick()');
    booleanFlag = true;
  }
  console.log(btn);
}

function clickFunction(){
  console.log('onclick');
}

function doubleClick(){
  console.log('doubleClick');
}
```

```html
<div id="displayStatus" class="display"></div>
<input type="button" id='btn' value="Click Me" onclick="clickFunction()" ondblclick="doubleClick()">
<input type="button" value="Switch Event" onclick="switchEvent()">
```

Comment: Not working ... getting error


`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
    at switchEvent (myjavascript.js:42)"`

Comment: @Indrajeet4192 But did you change your `html` code? I have added `id` 'btn' to the button to be able to catch it.

Comment: Added button id .... Not getting solutions... I am trying different ways but thanks

Comment: @Indrajeet4192 I've edited my answer, it has to work :) If not - please post your **whole** code and I will see where's the error.

Comment: `<html>
 <head>
 <title>HelloWorld</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/myjavascript.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="displayStatus"class="display" style="width: 150px;height: 50px;background-color: blue;"></div>

  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" onclick="clickFunction()" ondblclick="doubleClick()">
  <input type="button" value="Switch" onclick="switchEvent()">
 </body>
</html>`



is My inex.html and script is above your answer

Comment: @Indrajeet4192 Please move your `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/myjavascript.js"></script>` at the bottom of the `body` tag. I've checked it.

Comment: Working now ... Thanks for the answer.